# How to handle very big numbers in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've a python program that goes over tables in a DB (not mine) and for each column from type number it performs some mathematical operations such as stdev. However, there are some columns with very numbers and when I'm trying to execute:

```
select STDDEV(big_col) from table1;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Number out of representable range: type FIXED[SB16](38,0){not null}, value 3.67864e+38
```

Any idea how can I handle this one? It's ok for me just to ignore this values in this case but I don't want my query to fail.

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `big_col`?

Comment: `STDDEV(cast(big_col as double))`?

Comment: big_col  is from type NUMBER(38,0)

Comment: when I did STDDEV(cast(big_col as double)) I got results but they seem to be too small and not event close to e+38. does it make sense?

does it make sense?

Comment: The standard deviation is based on how much he values vary.  It would not necessarily have a magnitude related to the actual data.

Comment: yeah, makes sense. But why when I'm not doing the casting I'm getting the overflow?

Comment: Is this error thrown from Python or from Snowflake? When you run the SQL using the SnowSQL CLI or from the web UI are you getting the same error?

Comment: it's coming from snowflake.

Answer (score 6):

As **@dnoeth** mentioned in the comment section, casting the standard deviation as `DOUBLE` should fix the issue: `STDDEV(CAST(big_col as DOUBLE))`.

The **OP** asked how the resulting standard deviation seems to be significantly smaller than e+38 (which is the max number of digits that the `NUMBER` format can hold), then why do we need to cast this number as `DOUBLE`?

The reason for this lies in the standard deviation formula:

[image: Source: Wikipedia]

The first step in this process is to subtract the *mean* of the column from each individual value in that column. All those values are then squared. Now this square determines the 88  **upper bound** for the values that the `NUMBER` format needs to be able to handle before further arithmetic operations, like dividing by the number of records (`N`), and taking a square root reduce it down to the final answer. The final value of standard deviation that you get from this process could be significantly smaller than the sum of squares that's required to be calculated first.